# Changing the default comma separator for CSV files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, save

QGIS by default saves csv files with values separated by a comma, but I want to save my csv files with semicolons. When I save a vector layer as csv, I can choose if saving with a comma, semicolon, or others, but changing every time such option is tedious. Moreover, some plugins (e.g. 'Point sampling tool') save csv files without giving you the possibility to choose commas or semicolons.

Is there a way to set semicolons as the default in QGIS?

Answer (score 5):

It's hard-coded and you cannot change the default value until developers add  an option to change the default value.

This is the related source code of `Layer Options`: [Link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2182db8a5206ce1faadac56237b6427e8f10124c/src/core/qgsvectorfilewriter.cpp#L990)

```cpp
...
layerOptions.insert( QStringLiteral( "SEPARATOR" ), new QgsVectorFileWriter::SetOption(
                       QObject::tr( "Field separator character." ),
                       QStringList()
                       << QStringLiteral( "COMMA" )
                       << QStringLiteral( "SEMICOLON" )
                       << QStringLiteral( "TAB" ),
                       QStringLiteral( "COMMA" ) // Default value
                     ) );
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I modify this code in some way in the python console?

Comment: I don't think so. This is C++ code. You have to build QGIS from scratch.

Comment: You can use `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` method (in Python concole) 
 to export a layer to CSV by specifying a separator but I don't think it is easier than selecting it manually.